# Cassandra Java driver query ResultSet not stored in variable

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

```
        //Read data from Cassandra
        String query = "SELECT * FROM LABA_2.DATA LIMIT 5;";
        //Creating Cluster object
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
        //Creating Session object
        Session session = cluster.connect();
        //Getting the ResultSet
        ResultSet result = session.execute(query);
        System.out.println(result.all().size());
        System.out.println("AJFGJKABGSDKGJS");
        System.out.println(result.all().size());
        System.out.println("AJFGJKABGSDKGJS");
```

Output:

```
22/04/02 23:11:56 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /127.0.0.1:9042 added
5
AJFGJKABGSDKGJS
0
AJFGJKABGSDKGJS
```

In the first case size = 5, in the second = 0.

cassandra-driver - 3.11.0

Why results are different?

Answer (score 1):

Your test is invalid. Calling `ResultSet.all()` forces the driver to retrieve the whole result set in one go. The important thing to note here is that after calling `all()`, there is nothing left to retrieve.

When you call `all()` a second time, it returns nothing because you have already retrieved everything -- the list is exhausted and there's nothing left. Cheers!